# Deeply nested backbone.js objects cause errors?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working on a project using the following namespacing scheme:

```
var abc = {};
abc.models = {};
abc.views = {};

abc.models.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
```

When I seek to create a new collection I receive the following error

```
var collection = new abc.models.Collection({this:"that"});
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_reset'
```

when I moved the constructor to `abc.Collection` the error stopped and everything started working as needed.

Can someone please help me understand why this is?

I should also add that this is part of a multi-file application where each file is wrapped with the following:

```
(function($, abc){

//module contents here

}(jQuery, abc));
```

Comment: Works for me, check the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/dMBH8/) the issue should be somewhere else. Which Backbone version are you using?

Comment: Same version than in my jsFiddle.. check it out, why is working there?

Comment: That's interesting.  It could be there is something funky happening in the abc namespace that is messing with things.
I think for now I will make shallow these constructors.

Comment: There is an internal `_reset` method in Backbone.Collection but there's not enough information here to know what's going wrong.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of refactoring today.  It appears the issues have cleared up.  I just wish I knew exactly why.  Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 3):

this works:

```
var abc = {};
abc.models = {};
abc.views = {};
abc.models.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var collection = new abc.models.Collection([], {});
```

whereas this trips with [`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_reset'`](http://jsfiddle.net/sKXJF/):

```
var abc = {};
abc.models = {};
abc.views = {};
abc.models.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var collection = abc.models.Collection([], {});
```

The difference is not calling the constructor with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to a new Backbone Collection is an array of models and then a hash of options. Are you trying to pass in an array of models, if not then pass in the empty array: []

Comment: That's not the issue.  You can pass a simple object and if there is a model assigned to the collection, it will create the model on the fly.  The question here is why does the creation before fail when the Constructor is 2 levels deep into an object as opposed to 1.